# constant TCP request from ISTIO on the service port

Tags: istio, istio-gateway

Scenario: We use Istio as an ingress controller and service mesh in the Kubernetes cluster. my service opens 2 ports (for ex: 1234, 2345), and one of them for ex: 2345, relies upon direct TCP request handling so I have added TCP-based routing in the Istio virtual service and gateway. I have configured the health probe only for the 1234 port.

Problem: We are seeing constant TCP requests from the Istio ingress controller at intervals of 15-20 seconds. How can we prevent this from happening?

we tried removing the health probe rewrite based on the documentation given in Istio but that did not work.

Comment: Health probes are introduced as part of application manifests.  Istio will provide only feature for probe rewrite.  if you want to disable this, it needs to be done at your application definition end and istio will not have control on it.